# Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password - service credentials

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have just installed Biztalk 2010 server on my machine.
While configuring the server, in the service credentials, no matter what username password I provide, I get the above error.

I used the username password which I use to log into my machine.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a domain username, use the domain\userid. If its local then use .\userid